# 3ds envelope underlap?

Tags: 3dsmax

I'm rigging up a man in 3DS Max 2012, but I'm having some envelope problems. I have this man, but I can't ever seem to catch those nodes along his inner thigh so they protrude, as you can see in the picture.

[image: protrusion]

I've tried adjusting the numbers in `Radial Scale`, `Parent Overlap`, `Child Overlap`, `Strength`, and `Falloff`, and even the `Exclude` command to exclude the other limb but all with no success.

How can I somehow make these stray thigh vertexes conform into their thigh envelope?

Comment: Weight painting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using the envelopes, it is no precise enough,
open the Weight Table, select the vertex that is giving problems, like the one in you image. Give it a a 0.0 weight for all the bones,
Select the Thigh Bone and set the weight to 1.0

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've removed the signature from your post, please see: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures